# Finding $\int^{1}_{0}{p^x(1-p)^{n-x}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2} \left(\ln \left(a\frac{p}{1-p}\right)\right)^2\right\}}dp$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

I got the following integration and I could not figure it out.I wonder if it has a closed form,
$$\int^{1}_{0}{p^x(1-p)^{n-x}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2} \left(\ln \left(a\frac{p}{1-p}\right)\right)^2\right\}}dp$$
where $n>x$ and $n,x,$ and $a$ are some positive constants.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:
$$\begin{align}\exp\left\{-\frac12\left(\ln\left(a\frac p{1-p}\right)\right)^2\right\} & =\exp\left\{-\frac12\left((\ln a)^2+2\ln a\ln\left(\frac p{1-p}\right)+\left(\ln\left(\frac p{1-p}\right)\right)^2\right)\right\}\\
 & =\exp\left\{-\frac12(\ln a)^2\right\}\left(\frac p{1-p}\right)^{-\ln a}\exp\left\{-\frac12\left(\ln\left(\frac p{1-p}\right)\right)^2\right\}\end{align}$$
So $$\int_0^1p^x(1-p)^{n-x}\exp\left\{-\frac12\left(\ln\left(a\frac p{1-p}\right)\right)^2\right\}dp=\\
\exp\left\{-\frac12(\ln a)^2\right\}\int_0^1p^{x-\ln a}(1-p)^{n-x+\ln a}\exp\left\{-\frac12\left(\ln\left(\frac p{1-p}\right)\right)^2\right\}dp$$
Then if we let $u=\frac p{1-p}$, we find
$$\int_0^1p^{x-\ln a}(1-p)^{n-x+\ln a}\exp\left\{-\frac12\left(\ln\left(\frac p{1-p}\right)\right)^2\right\}dp= \\
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{u^{x-\ln a}}{(1+u)^{n+2}}\exp\left\{-\frac12\left(\ln u\right)^2\right\}du$$
Then if we let $u=e^y$, we get
$$\int_0^1p^x(1-p)^{n-x}\exp\left\{-\frac12\left(\ln\left(a\frac p{1-p}\right)\right)^2\right\}dp=\\
\exp\left\{-\frac12(\ln a)^2\right\}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{(x-\ln a+1)y}}{(1+e^y)^{n+2}}e^{-\frac12y^2}dy$$
Should probably be able to do a contour integral at this point, but I am out of time and have to leave it to another nurse to sew up the patient.

Comment: thanks for your partial solution.but I am still not able to solve the last integration that you have given.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that some more and it may well be that there is no clean answer. However, if you take the logarithmic derivative of the final integrand and set it equal to zero at $y=y_0$, then $$-y_0+x-\ln a+1-\frac{n+2}{1+e^{-y_0}}=0$$ So now you could let $$v=\frac1{\sqrt2}(y-y_0)$$ and this would set up the integral in perfect form for Gauss-Hermite quadrature and move the bump in the function near the origin. I would be hopeful of good numerical results. What are the ranges of $x$, $a$, and $n$?

Comment: Since I am not good at math, the things that you are saying sound like so complicated stuff to me.$n>x>=0$ and $infinity>a>0$.